# Format(Month(Date),"MMMM") Returns wrong month

Tags: excel, vba

Wondering why :

```
? Format(Now(), « MMMM ») return october
```

And

```
? Format(Month(Now()), « MMMM ») return January
```

However

```
? Month(Now()) return 10 ...
```

Any Idea why ?

Comment: It actually normal behaviour. Format expects the first argument to be a date when you use MMMM. 
Now() returns a date but Month(Now()) returns the number of the month rather than a date.  If you did Month("1-" & Month(Now()) & "-2020") it would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
? Format(Month(Now()), « MMMM »)
```

the expected date is "transformed" to a day value only. VBA then assumes the rest as year 1 and month 1. Hence the result becomes "January".

Simple test is to display:

```
? Format(Month(10), « MMMM »)
```

Comment: Hello it does display december and not January kinda weird

Comment: @Dorian Not weird at all if you understand how dates are stored.  Are they are different in VBA and Excel.  Hint:  The starting date (day 0) is different in VBA and Excel.